# CandleStickChart. Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts, candlestick-chart

I am trying to create a CandleStickChart using the Chart library (https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts). I have the following code:

```
func setChart(xValues: [String], valuesCandleChart: [Double]) {
    barChartView.descriptionText = ""
    barChartView.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the chart."

    var yValsCandleChart : [CandleChartDataEntry] = [CandleChartDataEntry]()
    for i in 0..<xValues.count {

        yValsCandleChart.append(ChartDataEntry(value: valuesCandleChart[i], xIndex: i))
    }
    let candleChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(yVals: yValsCandleChart, label: nil)
    let data: CombinedChartData = CombinedChartData(xVals: xValues)
    data.candleData = CandleChartData(xVals: xValues, dataSets: [candleChartDataSet]
    barChartView.data = data
    barChartView.leftAxis.customAxisMin = 0   
}
```

I am getting the error "Cannot convert value of type 'ChartDataEntry' to expected argument type 'CandleChartEntryType'"

EDIT:

I not have the following code:

```
func setChart(xValues: [String], valuesCandleChart: [[Double]]) {
    var yValsCandleChart : [CandleChartDataEntry] = [CandleChartDataEntry]()

    for i in 0..<xValues.count {
        print(" yValsCandleChart = \(valuesCandleChart[i])")
        yValsCandleChart.append(CandleChartDataEntry(xIndex: i, shadowH: valuesCandleChart[i][0], shadowL: valuesCandleChart[i][1], open: valuesCandleChart[i][2], close:  valuesCandleChart[i][0]))
    }

    let candleChartDataSet = CandleChartDataSet(yVals: yValsCandleChart, label: "test")


    let data: CombinedChartData = CombinedChartData(xVals: xValues)
    data.candleData = CandleChartData(xVals: xValues, dataSets: [candleChartDataSet])

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

let xValues = ["Jan","Feb"]
    let yValues: [[Double]] = [[10.0,1.5,5.5,3.6],[20.0,3.0,11.0,7.2]]

    setChart(xValues, valuesCandleChart: yValues)
}
```

A Chart is shown however the yValues are not plotted and i am unsure as to why. Please see the image below:

[image]

EDIT 1 :

I now have the code below:

```
func setChart(xValues: [String], valuesCandleChart: [[Double]]) {


    var yValsCandleChart : [CandleChartDataEntry] = [CandleChartDataEntry]()

    for i in 0..<xValues.count {
        print(" yValsCandleChart = \(valuesCandleChart[i])")
        let val = valuesCandleChart[i][0]
        let high = valuesCandleChart[i][1]
        let low = valuesCandleChart[i][2]
        let open = valuesCandleChart[i][3]
        let close = valuesCandleChart[i][4]

        yValsCandleChart.append(CandleChartDataEntry(xIndex: i, shadowH: val + high, shadowL: val + low, open: val + open, close: val - close))
    }

    let candleChartDataSet = CandleChartDataSet(yVals: yValsCandleChart, label: "test")
    let data: CombinedChartData = CombinedChartData(xVals: xValues)

    data.candleData = CandleChartData(xVals: xValues, dataSets: [candleChartDataSet])
    candleChartView.data = data
}
```

using : let yValues: [[Double]] = [[10.0,1.5,5.5,3.6,1.2],[20.0,3.0,11.0,7.2,1.2]]

Comment: is `ChartDataEntry` is the super class of  `CandleChartDataEntry ` ? any relation bw them?

Comment: Im not sure. I used 'ChartDataEntry' when using a BarChart and LineChart. when i use 'CandleChartDataEntry' i get an error "cannot invoke initialiser for type 'CandleChartDataEntry' with an argument list of type (value: Double, xIndex: Int)"

Comment: You're using a third party library, I take it? You need to go look at the docs for that library and see what the class hierarchy of the data objects is, and what you need to pass for each type of chart. (And you might want to edit your question to say "I am trying to create a CandleStickChart, using the open source library `CandleStickChart` available on <source>.")

Comment: @DuncanC Yes I'm using the Charts Library (danielgindib), thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong dataSet and entry class, use `CandleChartDataSet` and `CandleChartDataEntry`

You have to use its init methods.

> CandleChartDataEntry(xIndex: Int, shadowH: Double, shadowL: Double, open: Double, close: Double)

```
var yValsCandleChart : [CandleChartDataEntry] = [CandleChartDataEntry]()
for i in 0..<xValues.count {

    yValsCandleChart.append(CandleChartDataEntry(xIndex: yourInt, shadowH: yourDouble, shadowL: yourDouble, open: yourDouble, close: yourDouble))
}

let candleChartDataSet = CandleChartDataSet(yVals: yValsCandleChart, label: nil)
```

Update: This is how you create candle stick data entry from ChartsDemo

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    double mult = (range + 1);
    double val = (double) (arc4random_uniform(40)) + mult;
    double high = (double) (arc4random_uniform(9)) + 8.0;
    double low = (double) (arc4random_uniform(9)) + 8.0;
    double open = (double) (arc4random_uniform(6)) + 1.0;
    double close = (double) (arc4random_uniform(6)) + 1.0;
    BOOL even = i % 2 == 0;
    [yVals1 addObject:[[CandleChartDataEntry alloc] initWithXIndex:i shadowH:val + high shadowL:val - low open:even ? val + open : val - open close:even ? val - close : val + close]];
}
```

Comment: I am now getting the error "cannot invoke initialiser for type 'CandleChartDataEntry' with an argument list of type '(value: Double, index: Int)'" The valuesCandleChart = [5.0, 7.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 11.0, 7.0, 7.0, 5.0], is this the correct format?

Comment: that's because it does not inherit super class's init(value: Double, index: Int). answer updated. you should use CandleChartDataEntry's init methods.

Comment: Hi, I am still getting the error "cannot invoke initialiser for type 'CandleChartDataEntry' with an argument list of type '(xIndex: Int, shadowH: Double, shadowL: Double, open: Double, close: Double).Type". I have updated my code with the following error message.

Comment: you completely don't understand what is swift function parameters. it's your duty to fix the error. I have given enough information. code updated.

Comment: for the other question, you should checkout ChartsDemo's candle stick chart for reference how to create data. I have given one example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108621/discussion-between-jess-murray-and-wingzero).

Comment: I don't do chat. As I said, ChartsDemo is the place you should look at how does it draw the chart.

Comment: I have tried using the ChartsDemo however the code fragments are using objective-C, similarly to the update you posted. The only swift examples I can see which uses something similar to what i am trying is the BarChart and LineChart. Apologies for being an annoyance however i attempted to convert your update code to a swift version which i could use however i get the same problem with it not showing as expected

Comment: take your time to learn from the Demo it's all there. I cannot offer more help.